# In-app update out of the Play Store?

Tags: applications, updates

I have a local Android application,  a custom scanner application, that is used in a cabinet factory production environment.

This application is not published on the Play Store. It is installed using a link to the apk on our local network. We do install apps and app updates one by one. We already have around 100 scanners. So, it's a pain updating all those one by one.

The question is: Can an in-app update be implemented in this way? I mean, without using the Play Store? Like writing in-app update code in the main activity but pointing to the link to the apk on our local network instead of the Play Store.

In other words, putting the new apk on the local server and using the link for the in-app update code, instead of uploading the app to the Play Store?

I've been looking for information for a few days unsuccessfully.

NOTE: I'm trying to do this out of the Play Store because the scanners in the production environment do not have internet access for security and safety purposes. They only have access to the local network via Wi-Fi.

Comment: An app can update itself (see e.g. f-droid store), but to actually install the app update Android shows a user consent page where you have to select the "Install" button. Only system apps can install apps without user consent.

Comment: MDM solutions are also an alternative, as they may also provide a built-in store to push app updates to multiple devices directly.

Comment: @Robert, do you have any tutorial that I can follow, I'm completely new on this. So I'm kind of lost. I checked documentation, but not sure if I need to create kind of a local f-droid store or something like that. Because remember that the devices have no access to internet. Also, each device needs to have f-droid app installed on it?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: @AndrewT. Which MDM do you recommend, please let me know.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You only need to download the APK file and then trigger installation for the APK file. There are a lot of examples on https://Stackoverflow.com. How you organize the apps on server side is up to you.